# Updating Heroku Postgres from dev to basic

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to update my database from Dev to Basic on heroku. I followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups) but after heroku `pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHATEVER` I wanted to check if my database had everything, so I just went and looked on the website and for the basic version it says

```
![Data Size 0 B
Tables  0
PG Version ?][1]
```

The basic

[image: Basic Plan]

While it should be

[image: Dev Plan]

I am not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Website aside, does the database function properly when you access it from your application?

Comment: @AndrewGorcester I havent taken it out of the maintenance mode yet. do you want me to do that and try maybe saving some data to the database?

Comment: also, now it shows the right tables (Tables:56) in both but the data size is still 0 B in the Basic plan one

Comment: It's your call, but I think it's more likely that the web panel isn't working than the database isn't working.  And if the database is working and is up to the capacity of your new plan, then there's not really any problem.  Presumably the web panel will update with the new info eventually.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester yes I took it off maintenance, it seems to work just fine but I am still reluctant to delete my dev plan database yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table and database size is computed via an asynchronous process. This can sometimes take a little while to show. If you've recently migrated then you should try connecting with `heroku pg:psql` then running:

```
VACUUM ANALYZE;
```

This will ensure Postgres has proper stastics then reports the tables correctly for when Heroku asks about the table size. Additionally you could manually explore your database once connected to ensure your data is there:

```
\dt                    --- to display tables
SELECT * FROM foo;     --- to ensure data is there on a specific table
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. :) but since it was my first time migrating, so I didnt want to take any chances